# Python hex digest to integer

Tags: python, hex

Many online gambling games use a function that converts a hash into a decimal from 0-(usually 2^52).

Here's some code I grabbed that works fine, but I don't understand why it works:

```py
def get_result(hash):
    hm = hmac.new(str.encode(hash),b'', hashlib.sha256) #hashing object

    h = hm.hexdigest() #hex digest, 32 bytes 256 bit
    print(h) #Something like 848ab848c6486d4f64
    c = int(h,16) 
    print(c) #numbers only, 77 numbers long...?
    if (c % 33 == 0): 
        return 1
    h = int(h[:13],16)
    return (((100 * E - h) / (E - h)) // 1) / 100.0
```

The part of the code that I don't understand is the conversion from h to c. h is a hex digest, so it is base-16. The python documentation says that the int(a,b) function converts the string a into a base-b integer. Here's my question:

1. How can an integer number be base-16? Isn't the definition of decimal base-10 (0-9)? Where do the extra 6 come from?
2. As far as I'm aware, a single hex digit can be stored by 4 bits, or 1/2 a byte. So a hex string of 64 length will occupy 32 bytes. Does this mean that any base of this data will also be 32 bytes? (converting the hex string to base-n, n being anything)
3. What does the fact that the c variable is always 77 digits long mean?

Comment: Hexidecimal is a base 16 number system. Typically it is represented by 4 bits (half a byte). So you get 2^4, or 16 possible values from 0000, 0001, ... to 1111. In hex we use letters a,b,c,d,e,f to count pass 9. the `int` function converts a string that represents a base n integer represented by a string into a python integer. When you go to print the int after this conversion you will get a base 10 output like normal. so `10 == int("a", 16)`

Comment: Also you see 77 digits because 2^256 ~= 1.16e+77 in decimal.

Answer (score 3):

> How can an integer number be base-16? Where do the extra 6 come from?

This is known as the [hexadecimal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

> Isn't the definition of decimal base-10 (0-9)?

Integer and decimal are not synonyms. You can have a integer in base 2 instead of base 10.

> As far as I'm aware, a single hex digit can be stored by 4 bits, or 1/2 a byte. So a hex string of 64 length will occupy 32 bytes.

There are two different concepts: a hex string and a hex integer.

When you type in Python, for example, `"8ff"`, you're creating a hex **string** of length 3. A string is an array of characters. A character is (under the hood) a 1-byte integer. Therefore, you're storing **3 bytes**¹ (about your second statement, a hex string of length 64 will actually occupy 64 bytes).

Now, when you type in Python `0x8ff`, you're creating a hex **integer** of 3 digits. If you print it, it'll show 2303, because of the conversion from base-16 (8ff, hex) to base-10 (2303, dec). A single integer stores 4 bytes², so you're storing **4 bytes**.

> Does this mean that any base of this data will also be 32 bytes? (converting the hex string to base-n, n being anything)

It depends, what type of data?

- A string of length 3 will always occupy 3 bytes (let's ignore Unicode), it doesn't matter if its `"8ff"` or `"123"`.
- A string of length 10 will always occupy 10 bytes, it doesn't matter if its `"85d8afff"` or `"ef08c0e38e"`.
- An integer will always occupy 4 bytes³, it doesn't matter if its 10 or 1000000.

> What does the fact that the c variable is always 77 digits long mean?

[As @flakes noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552661/python-hex-digest-to-integer#comment119401678_67552661), that's because 2^256 ~= 1.16e+77 in decimal.

---

¹ Actually a string of length 3 stores 4 bytes: three for its characters and one for the null terminator.

¹ Let's ignore that integers in Python are unbounded.

² If it's lesser than 2,147,483,647 (signed) or 4,294,967,295 (unsigned).

Comment: Be aware that in Python string characters are not always a single byte depending on the encoding. You can have things like emojis in utf8 that break this rule.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant in "let's ignore Unicode".

Comment: @flakes but a hexidecimal string will contain nothing but ASCII characters, and modern versions of Python will optimize those to a single byte per character.

Comment: I was commenting mostly on the language used in "A character is (under the hood) a 1-byte integer."

Comment: Does Python differentiate between signed and unsigned `int` objects?  I didn't think it did.

Comment: That's because I'm not sure how Python implements an `int` in Cython (most common implementation), so I just put it for the sake of convenience.

Comment: None come to mind, but I'm wondering if there are other common character encodings apart from unicode (or subsets of unicode) that are implemented with multi-byte characters.